# Jenkins displays connection timeout when cloning

Tags: jenkins

I am having a problem with my Jenkins pipeline which was working very well some few days ago but suddenly, I am not able to clone from GitLab as I did before.
I connecting using basic http and each time i try to launch the pipeline, I get timeout error. Another error which is being displayed at the bottom of the console is **ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffmxJ.png)

Comment: Can you please post full logs.

Comment: Hi, i edited my post and attached an image of the logs

Comment: check your credentials, may be some type in username/password.